# What is causing my DbUpdateConcurrencyException?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, azure-servicebus-topics

In my .NET Core Web API, I have implemented the transactional outbox pattern to monitor a database table and publish messages to an Azure Service Bus topic whenever a record appears in the database table. This takes place within a hosted service class that inherits from `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.BackgroundService`. This is a stripped-down version of what I have:

```
 protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            try
            {
                IEnumerable<RelayMessage> messagesToSend = new List<RelayMessage>();
            // _scopeFactory is an implementation of Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceScopeFactory:  
            using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();

                while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    messagesToSend = await dbContext.RelayMessage.ToListAsync();

                    foreach (var message in messagesToSend)
                    {

                        try
                        {
                            await SendMessageToAzureServiceBus(message);
                            dbContext.RelayMessage.Remove(message);
                            dbContext.SaveChanges();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Log.Error(ex, $"Could not send message with id {message.RelayMessageId}.");
                        }
                    }

                    await Task.Delay(5000, stoppingToken);
                }
            }

            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex, "Exception thrown while processing messages.");
        }
```

The records are being deleted from the database, but the following exception gets thrown on the call to `SaveChanges()`:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ThrowAggregateUpdateConcurrencyException(Int32 commandIndex, Int32 expectedRowsAffected, Int32 rowsAffected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeResultSetWithoutPropagation(Int32 commandIndex, RelationalDataReader reader)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.Consume(RelationalDataReader reader)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IList`1 entries)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1 entriesToSave)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(DbContext _, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at ReinsuranceReferenceSystemApi.Services.ServiceBus.ParticipantPublishingService.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
```

I did check out the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency) in the exception message, but am not sure if the information applies to my situation. The RelayMessage instance is created and saved to the database (in a method not shown here), then this method reads it and deletes it. There aren't any modifications of this type anywhere in the application, so I'm unclear on how this could be a concurrency issue.

I'd appreciate any help.

EDIT:
Here's the registration of my DbContext in Startup.cs:

```
 services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(o =>
 {                    
   o.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString"));
 });
```

Comment: can I see the Context register in Startup?

Comment: @go I added the context registration.

Comment: There are many different methods. I wonder how you did it. The problem may be there.

Comment: Disclaimer: I know nothing about Azure; we use AWS. But usually this error means something else changed the db underneath your transaction. How many instances of your web api are running? Are you sure only the one instance can be trying to process the same record at once?

Comment: @RobC Did you resolve this? What was the fix? I have almost exactly the same design and same exception. Can't seem to figure out why. Thanks